# Microsoft flow and sending emails

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, flow, microsoft-flow

At my Organization, we use g-mail as a our email provider. I have a basic Microsoft flow approval process with a SharePoint list. The process works like this

1. One person from help desk puts a request in
2. I get an notification via email that there is a request waiting for my approval
3. I check it out and the request is either approved and denied
4. that one person gets an email saying its been approved or denied

This works perfectly with one person because the email address was hard coded in the process. Management loves it and decides to make it available to all persons in helpdesk. So now any person in helpdesk can send a request. I thought the best way to make it the process be dynamic was to use the variable called 'Created By Email'. That did not work because it is trying to send an email to 'thereemail@onmymicrosft.com' and not to 'thereemail@gmail.com'. I checked the proxy addresses and some people have 'thereemail@onmymicrosft.com' as the default.

**Is there a way to change the default proxy address to 'thereemail@gmail.com' or to change it to 'thereemail@gmail.com'?**

**Is there a way I can point to the alternate email address instead of the created by email in the flow?**

Comment: Why not create a second list with the the agent name and corresponding gmail email address. You can grab that value with the Get Items action and add the Get Items dynamic value of the gmail address